# Grouped results according to one field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 2 significant columns, one with a date and time, and another one with an amount of seconds (so, an integer).

I wish to get how many seconds I have for each day of the week, and for each hour of the day.

I managed to have this information with 24 rows for each day of the week, with the dow in one column, the hour in another one, and the amount of seconds in the last one.
What I would love to have is it in just 7 rows, with one column being the dow and the other one an array or something with the 24 amounts of seconds.

Any idea on how to get rid of it?

The query I ended with is:

```
SELECT dow, hour, sum(duration/60) as minutes 
  FROM( SELECT duration, 
               extract( 'dow' from datetime ) as dow, 
               extract( 'hour' from datetime ) as hour 
          FROM "statistics" 
          WHERE datetime between '2013-10-01' and '2013-11-01' 
            and duration >= 300 
      ) as foo
   GROUP BY dow, hour 
   ORDER BY dow, hour
```

And this gives me a result like:

```
 dow | hour | minuts 
-----+------+--------
   0 |    0 |    742
   0 |    1 |    572
   0 |    2 |    634
   0 |    3 |    208
   0 |    4 |    333
   0 |    5 |    302
   0 |    6 |    183
   0 |    7 |    108
   0 |    8 |    135
   0 |    9 |    201
   0 |   10 |    369
   0 |   11 |    429
   0 |   12 |    340
   0 |   13 |    439
   0 |   14 |    572
   0 |   15 |    420
   0 |   16 |    636
   0 |   17 |    958
   0 |   18 |    878
   0 |   19 |   1176
   0 |   20 |    995
   0 |   21 |    740
   0 |   22 |    783
   0 |   23 |    857
   1 |    0 |    474
   1 |    1 |    576
   1 |    2 |    431
   1 |    3 |    157
   1 |    4 |    140
   1 |    5 |     55
   1 |    6 |     17
   1 |    8 |    118
   1 |    9 |    356
   1 |   10 |    994
   1 |   11 |    930
   1 |   12 |   1177
   1 |   13 |   1228
   1 |   14 |    896
   1 |   15 |   1072
   1 |   16 |   1254
   1 |   17 |   1764
   1 |   18 |   1303
   1 |   19 |   1176
   1 |   20 |   1314
   1 |   21 |   1003
   1 |   22 |   1161
   1 |   23 |    811
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tossing in `array_agg()`, e.g.:

```
WITH
monthly_stats as (
SELECT duration, 
       extract( 'dow' from datetime ) as dow, 
       extract( 'hour' from datetime ) as hour 
FROM "statistics" 
WHERE datetime >= '2013-10-01'
  AND datetime < '2013-10-01' + interval '1 month'
  AND duration >= 300 
),
daily_stats as (
SELECT dow, hour, sum(duration/60) as minutes 
FROM monthly_stats
GROUP BY dow, hour 
)
SELECT dow, array_agg(minutes ORDER BY hour)
FROM daily_stats
GROUP BY dow
ORDER BY dow
```

Answer (score 0):

for those not using PostgreSQL, I can think of 2 solutions.

Assuming (for this example) a results table containing the columns dow,hour and mins
then you can..

1) Do a rather messy multi-join (Oracle and SQLServer versions shown  in a moment)
2) or write a CONCAT_MYSTATS Function that can return the results. For SQLITE you
   can use the existing GROUP_CONCAT aggregate Function.

**Lazy Version Code
ORACLE:**

```
SELECT      d.dow,
    MAX(NVL(d0.hour,0)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d0.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d1.hour,1)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d1.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d2.hour,2)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d2.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d3.hour,3)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d3.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d4.hour,4)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d4.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d5.hour,5)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d5.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d6.hour,6)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d6.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d7.hour,7)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d7.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d8.hour,8)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d8.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d9.hour,9)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d9.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d10.hour,10)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d10.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d11.hour,11)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d11.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d12.hour,12)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d12.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d13.hour,13)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d13.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d14.hour,14)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d14.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d15.hour,15)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d15.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d16.hour,16)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d16.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d17.hour,17)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d17.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d18.hour,18)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d18.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d19.hour,19)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d19.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d20.hour,20)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d20.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d21.hour,21)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d21.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d22.hour,22)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d22.mins,0))
    || ';' || MAX(NVL(d23.hour,23)) || '=' || SUM(NVL(d23.mins,0))
FROM        (SELECT distinct dow FROM mystats) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d0 ON d0.dow = d.dow AND d0.hour=0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d1 ON d1.dow = d.dow AND d1.hour=1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d2 ON d2.dow = d.dow AND d2.hour=2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d3 ON d3.dow = d.dow AND d3.hour=3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d4 ON d4.dow = d.dow AND d4.hour=4
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d5 ON d5.dow = d.dow AND d5.hour=5
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d6 ON d6.dow = d.dow AND d6.hour=6
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d7 ON d7.dow = d.dow AND d7.hour=7
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d8 ON d8.dow = d.dow AND d8.hour=8
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d9 ON d9.dow = d.dow AND d9.hour=9
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d10 ON d10.dow = d.dow AND d10.hour=10
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d11 ON d11.dow = d.dow AND d11.hour=11
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d12 ON d12.dow = d.dow AND d12.hour=12
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d13 ON d13.dow = d.dow AND d13.hour=13
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d14 ON d14.dow = d.dow AND d14.hour=14
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d15 ON d15.dow = d.dow AND d15.hour=15
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d16 ON d16.dow = d.dow AND d16.hour=16
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d17 ON d17.dow = d.dow AND d17.hour=17
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d18 ON d18.dow = d.dow AND d18.hour=18
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d19 ON d19.dow = d.dow AND d19.hour=19
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d20 ON d20.dow = d.dow AND d20.hour=20
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d21 ON d21.dow = d.dow AND d21.hour=21
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d22 ON d22.dow = d.dow AND d22.hour=22
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d23 ON d23.dow = d.dow AND d23.hour=23
GROUP BY    d.dow
```

SQLSERVER:

```
SELECT      d.dow,
    CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d0.hour,0))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d0.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d1.hour,1))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d1.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d2.hour,2))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d2.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d3.hour,3))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d3.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d4.hour,4))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d4.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d5.hour,5))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d5.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d6.hour,6))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d6.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d7.hour,7))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d7.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d8.hour,8))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d8.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d9.hour,9))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d9.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d10.hour,10))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d10.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d11.hour,11))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d11.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d12.hour,12))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d12.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d13.hour,13))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d13.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d14.hour,14))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d14.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d15.hour,15))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d15.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d16.hour,16))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d16.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d17.hour,17))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d17.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d18.hour,18))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d18.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d19.hour,19))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d19.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d20.hour,20))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d20.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d21.hour,21))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d21.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d22.hour,22))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d22.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
    + ';' + CAST(MAX(ISNULL(d23.hour,23))  AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(SUM(ISNULL(d23.mins,0))  AS VARCHAR)
FROM        (SELECT distinct dow FROM mystats) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d0 ON d0.dow = d.dow AND d0.hour=0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d1 ON d1.dow = d.dow AND d1.hour=1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d2 ON d2.dow = d.dow AND d2.hour=2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d3 ON d3.dow = d.dow AND d3.hour=3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d4 ON d4.dow = d.dow AND d4.hour=4
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d5 ON d5.dow = d.dow AND d5.hour=5
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d6 ON d6.dow = d.dow AND d6.hour=6
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d7 ON d7.dow = d.dow AND d7.hour=7
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d8 ON d8.dow = d.dow AND d8.hour=8
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d9 ON d9.dow = d.dow AND d9.hour=9
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d10 ON d10.dow = d.dow AND d10.hour=10
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d11 ON d11.dow = d.dow AND d11.hour=11
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d12 ON d12.dow = d.dow AND d12.hour=12
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d13 ON d13.dow = d.dow AND d13.hour=13
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d14 ON d14.dow = d.dow AND d14.hour=14
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d15 ON d15.dow = d.dow AND d15.hour=15
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d16 ON d16.dow = d.dow AND d16.hour=16
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d17 ON d17.dow = d.dow AND d17.hour=17
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d18 ON d18.dow = d.dow AND d18.hour=18
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d19 ON d19.dow = d.dow AND d19.hour=19
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d20 ON d20.dow = d.dow AND d20.hour=20
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d21 ON d21.dow = d.dow AND d21.hour=21
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d22 ON d22.dow = d.dow AND d22.hour=22
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d23 ON d23.dow = d.dow AND d23.hour=23
GROUP BY    d.dow
```

**CONCAT Function Version:
ORACLE:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONCAT_MYSTATS (pDOW IN INTEGER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
ALIST       VARCHAR2(200) DEFAULT '';
BEGIN
FOR REC IN (    SELECT      h.HR            AS HOUR,
                SUM(NVL(d.mins,0))  AS MINS
        FROM        (SELECT 0 AS Hr FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 11 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 12 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 13 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 14 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 15 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 16 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 17 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 18 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 19 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 20 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 21 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 22 AS HR FROM dual
                 UNION ALL SELECT 23 AS HR FROM dual) h
                LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d
                    ON d.hour = h.HR
        WHERE       d.dow = pDOW
        GROUP BY    h.HR
        ORDER BY    1
        )
LOOP
    --
        IF NVL(ALIST,' ') !=' ' THEN
        ALIST := ALIST || ';';
    END IF;
    ALIST := ALIST || REC.HOUR || '=' || REC.MINS;
END LOOP;
RETURN ALIST;
END;
/
```

and then

```
SELECT      d.dow,
        CONCAT_MYSTATS(d.dow)
FROM        (SELECT distinct dow FROM mystats) d
```

**SQLSERVER Version**

```
CREATE FUNCTION CONCAT_MYSTATS (@pDOW INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ALIST      VARCHAR(200);
SET @ALIST='';
DECLARE @QHR        INTEGER;
DECLARE @QMINS      INTEGER;
--
DECLARE cREC CURSOR FOR
    SELECT      h.HR            AS HOUR,
            SUM(ISNULL(d.mins,0))   AS MINS
    FROM        (SELECT 0 AS Hr
             UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 11 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 12 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 13 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 14 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 15 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 16 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 17 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 18 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 19 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 20 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 21 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 22 AS HR
             UNION ALL SELECT 23 AS HR) h
            LEFT OUTER JOIN mystats d
            ON d.hour = h.HR
    WHERE       d.dow = @pDOW
    GROUP BY    h.HR
    ORDER BY    1;
--
OPEN cREC
FETCH cREC INTO @QHR,@QMINS;    
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    --
    IF @ALIST!='' SET @ALIST=@ALIST + ';';
    SET @ALIST=@ALIST + CAST(@QHR AS VARCHAR) + '=' + CAST(@QMINS AS VARCHAR);
    --
FETCH cREC INTO @QHR,@QMINS;    
END
CLOSE cREC
DEALLOCATE cREC
RETURN @ALIST;
END
```

and then

```
 SELECT     d.dow,
    dbo.CONCAT_MYSTATS(d.dow)
 FROM       (SELECT distinct dow FROM mystats) d
```

and finally, for SQLITE all you need to do is

```
 SELECT     d.dow,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.hour || '=' || d.mins,';')
FROM        mystats d
GROUP BY    d.dow
```

Working example (SQLITE) at 
http://www.datagloop.com/?ACTION=LOGIN&USERNAME=DATAGLOOP/SO_CONCAT